# Where can I find out more about the changes made from one version of Civi to another?

Tags: issues, 4.6, 4.6.8

Do you need to find what changes were made from one Civi version to another - say 4.6.6 to 4.6.9? Where can you find that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'Jira'  - the issue tracking platform used by the CiviCRM project - at 
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:changelog-panel

Answer (score 1):

On Jira at issues.civicrm.org, you can get the specific version that issues have as "fix for":
[https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/issues/?jql=project = CRM AND fixVersion = 4.6.10](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20=%20CRM%20AND%20fixVersion%20=%204.6.10)

(Yes, those are spaces in the URL--your browser will replace them with "%20" for you.)

Just replace "4.6.10" in the URL with the version number you're interested in, or just use the filter above the results:
[image: screeenshot of Jira]